# Reading text of a pdf using PDFBOX occasionally returns \r\n

Tags: java, pdfbox

I’m currently using PDFBox to read the text of a set of pdfs that I’ve inherited.

I’m only interested in reading the text, not making any changes to the file.

The code that works for most of the files is:

```
   File pdfFile = myPath.toFile();
   PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile );
   Writer sw = new StringWriter();
   PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
   stripper.setStartPage( 1 );
   stripper.writeText( document,  sw );
   String documentText = sw.toString()
```

For most files, I wind up with the text in the documentText field.

But, for 3 of 24 files, the documentText content for the first file is “\r\n”, for the second “\r\n\r\n”, and for the third “\r\n\r\n\r\n:, But the three files are not consecutive. Multiple good files are between each of these files.

The File is derived from a java.nio.Path. The WindowsFileAttribute that is part of the Path has a size of 279K, so the file is not empty on disk.

I can open the file and view the data, and it looks like the other files that my code reads.

I’m using Java 8.0.121, and PDFBox 2.0.4. (this is the latest version, I believe.)

Any suggestions? Is there a better way to read the text? (I’m not interested in the formatting, or fonts used, just the text.)

Thanks.

Comment: I believe there are different versions of pdf's this might be the cause.

Comment: Please share the pdf files in question for analysis.

Comment: The pdfs are reports that I cannot share. I believe that the problem with these three files is at that they really have no text, but are pdf-wrappers around images of pages with text. My challenge now is to write code to determine that there are images definitively so I can put out a reason for why I cannot get the text to parse. It is strange that the same lab created all of these files, including the three that are different. I would have expected them to have "a" process to create the results of their analysis and convert it to a pdf.

Answer (score -1):

## Reading multiple PDF docs using pdfbox in java

```java
package readwordfile;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.TextPosition;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This is an example on how to extract words from PDF document
 *
 * @author saravanan
 */
public class GetWordsFromPDF extends PDFTextStripper {

    static List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    public GetWordsFromPDF() throws IOException {
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException If there is an error parsing the document.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String files;
//        FileWriter fs = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\saravanan\\Desktop\\New Text Document (2).txt");  
//        FileInputStream fstream1 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\saravanan\\Desktop\\New Text Document (2).txt");
//        DataInputStream in1 = new DataInputStream(fstream1);
//        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));
        String path = "C:\\Users\\saravanan\\Desktop\\New folder\\";  //local folder path name
        File folder = new File(path);

        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                if (files.endsWith(".pdf") || files.endsWith(".PDF")) {

                    String nfiles = "C:\\Users\\saravanan\\Desktop\\New folder\\";
                    String fileName1 = nfiles + files;
                    System.out.print("\n\n" + files+"\n");
                    PDDocument document = null;
                    try {
                        document = PDDocument.load(new File(fileName1));
                        PDFTextStripper stripper = new GetWordsFromPDF();
                        stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
                        stripper.setStartPage(0);
                        stripper.setEndPage(document.getNumberOfPages());

                        Writer dummy = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
                        stripper.writeText(document, dummy);
                        int x = 0;

                        System.out.println("");
                        for (String word : words) {
                            if (word.startsWith("xxxxxx")) { //here you can give your pdf doc starting word 
                                x = 1;
                            }
                            if (x == 1) {
                                if (!(word.endsWith("YYYYYY"))) { //here you can give your pdf doc ending word 
                                    System.out.print(word + " ");
                                    // fs.write(word);                                   
                                } else {
                                    x = 0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (document != null) {
                            document.close();
                            words.clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Override the default functionality of PDFTextStripper.writeString()
     *
     * @param str
     * @param textPositions
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    @Override
    protected void writeString(String str, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
        String[] wordsInStream = str.split(getWordSeparator());
        if (wordsInStream != null) {
            for (String word : wordsInStream) {
                words.add(word);    //store the pdf content into the List
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You answer is just placing a bunch of code? Try to explain to the SO what is your logic behind this.

Comment: In the above program you can read multiple pdf file as well as extract some contents from those pdf files with the help of startswith and endswith function in java. guys " don't forget to add PDFBOX " library file i have attached the library file screen shot link: i.stack.imgur.com/nX6dy.png

Comment: The OP has a very specific problem: *'But, for 3 of 24 files, the documentText content for the first file is “\r\n”, for the second “\r\n\r\n”, and for the third “\r\n\r\n\r\n"'*. Your answer in no way elaborates on this issue, let alone offers a viable solution for it. And your library file screenshot shows a wild collection of versions of zip'ed PDFBox related jars and a single relevant entry...

Comment: 6 different pdfbox versions in your libraries folder?!